# redirect after adding app to a page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-rest-api, facebook-apps

I'm working on an app our customers will install on their page. I try to make the following sequence without success :

1. get user permissions
2. let the user choose the page he wants to install the app
3. add the app to his page with facebook.com/add.php?api_key=xxxx&pages&page=xxxx
4. Redirect the user to our page app where he will be able to configure it

This last step is making me crazy. The user is allways redirected to his page and I don't know how to change the page to target. We try the next parameter in the add.php link but it does nothing

Any idea on the way to do it ?

Thanks in advance folks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the &redirect_uri=YOUR_URL paramater?

Comment: Yes, and also the &next=YOUR_URL paramater but it still redirects to user's page

Comment: We find the solution :

first get the access token https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?format=json&grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=xxxx&client_secret=xxxxx

then https://api.facebook.com/method/admin.setAppProperties?access_token=xxxxx&properties={%27post_authorize_redirect_url%27:%27youturl%27}